# How can i validate and verify my project' code

Tags: validation, verification

Our teacher said choose a topic(i choose social media analytics tool) and find a code about it(from github) then:

Analyze / test (if possible real-world) code to validate and verify the software.

Design test cases and apply various testing approaches (functional, structural, …).
I do not how to it exatly can someone help and give an idea

I do not what to do